# Understanding the need for this `const&` specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, overloading, guideline-support-library

In the Guidelines Support Library there is a class called `final_action` (essentially the well known ScopeGuard). There are 2 free-standing convenience functions to generate this templated class:

```
// finally() - convenience function to generate a final_action
template <class F>
inline final_action<F> finally(const F& f) noexcept
{
    return final_action<F>(f);
}

template <class F>
inline final_action<F> finally(F&& f) noexcept
{
    return final_action<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

(source: https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/64a7dae4c6fb218a23b3d48db0eec56a3c4d5234/include/gsl/gsl_util#L71-L82)

What is the need for the first one? If we only had the second one (using the forwarding , a.k.a. universal, references) wouldn't it do the same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's consider the *perfectly-forwarding* version:

- When called with an rvalue, it will return `final_action<F>(static_cast<F&&>(f))`.
- When called with an lvalue, it will return `final_action<F&>(f)`.

Let's now consider the `const F&` overload:

- When called both an lvalue or rvalue, it will return `final_action<F>(f)`.

As you can see, there is an important difference:

- Passing a non-`const` lvalue reference to `finally` will produce a wrapper that stores a `F&`
- Passing a `const` lvalue reference to `finally` will produce a wrapper that stores a `F`

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AjZaiyJObe5JFpVr)

---

I am not sure why it was deemed necessary to have the `const F&` overload.

This is the implementation of `final_action`:

```
template <class F>
class final_action
{
public:
    explicit final_action(F f) noexcept : f_(std::move(f)), invoke_(true) {}

    final_action(final_action&& other) noexcept 
        : f_(std::move(other.f_)), invoke_(other.invoke_)
    {
        other.invoke_ = false;
    }

    final_action(const final_action&) = delete;
    final_action& operator=(const final_action&) = delete;

    ~final_action() noexcept
    {
        if (invoke_) f_();
    }

private:
    F f_;
    bool invoke_;
};
```

Unless I am missing something, instanting `final_action<F&>` doesn't really make sense, as `f_(std::move(f))` will not compile.

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PMedisiRwEQhEeZS)

So I think this should have just been:

```
template <class F>
inline final_action<F> finally(F&& f) noexcept
{
    return final_action<std::decay_t<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Ultimately, I think that the implementation of `finally` in GSL incorrect/unoptimal (i.e. redundant, has code repetition).